# How to use "git grep" to search for 8-bit encoded text in a files with the same encoding

Tags: windows, git, grep, git-grep

I have a project where the files are 8-bit encoded (Win-1251).
Can you please tell me if there is a way using *git grep* to find a phrase composed of characters from the top of the ASCII table (i.e. with codes from 0x80 to 0xFF)?

I work under Windows. I use the console to work with git, and it seems that the text that I pass to search in *git grep* (for example, `git grep "привет"`) is perceived by this utility as a sequence of utf-8 characters, i.e. *git grep* is actually trying to find the sequence of bytes "\xD0\xBF\xD1\x80\xD0\xB8\xD0\xB2\xD0\xB5\xD1\x82".

I also tried to execute this command for searching: `git grep "\xEF\xF0\xE8\xE2\xE5\xF2"` (where byte sequence in quotes is ASCII codes of `"привет"` word in Win-1251), but it turned out that grep does not accept escape sequences.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `-P` flag : Perl regexp should understand escape sequences

---

You could write your search patterns in a file, you can then tell git grep to read the search patterns from this file : `git grep -f patterns.txt ...`

The bonus of a file is that you can more easily control the encoding of its content.

You can also use this feature to build a script, that would turn a UTF8 string and encode it as Win-1251 before feeding it to `git grep` :

```
pattern=$1
shift
echo $pattern | iconv -t WINDOWS-1251 > /tmp/rusgrep-pattern
git grep -f /tmp/rusgrep-pattern "$@"
```

Comment: Thank you! This options works. This solution can already be used. But it may be possible to somehow specify a string of characters to search for, so that each time you do not translate the string into a sequence of bytes?

Comment: Thank you again. The solution by creating a separate file "pattern.txt" is quite suitable. I don't have to do this kind of search very often (of course, more often I have to search for words consisting of characters from the first half of the ASCII table), so it's not too difficult to create a file (but it would be quite difficult to translate word or several words into a escape sequence of hex codes).

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bstpierre/1170837) and [@LeGEC 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63100790/791430), you can do something like this -

```
git grep -P "$(iconv -f utf-8 <(echo -n 'привет') -t 'Windows-1251' | od -tx1 | sed -e 's/^[0-9]* //' -e '$d' -e 's/^/ /' -e 's/ /\\x/g')"
```

You can put this in a bash function

```
function gitbingrep {
    git grep -P "$(iconv -f utf-8 <(echo -n "$1") -t 'Windows-1251' | od -tx1 | sed -e 's/^[0-9]* //' -e '$d' -e 's/^/ /' -e 's/ /\\x/g')"
}
```

And now you can simply run `gitbingrep привет`

Comment: Your expression didn't work in my case. Maybe it's not for the Windows console?

Comment: Yeah I doubt it'll work on a Windows console... Try Git Bash maybe? It works on Linux in any case. You can use WSL if you really want it to work on a Windows machine

Comment: I tried it in "git bash" console too, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: So use WSL, or try to adjust it to work in the Git Bash console, shouldn't be too bad. Don't have a Windows machine to test on so can't help